# asciidoc - Inline Conditional Inclusion Macros

Tags: asciidoc

Is there a way to do **inline** conditional inclusion macros in [AsciiDoc](http://www.methods.co.nz/asciidoc/chunked/ch21.html)?

I would like to be able to do something like:

> The control’s data source property is ifdef::wpf[`DataContext`] ifdef::web[`dataSource`] and accepts a collection of view model objects.

Is there a syntax variation that would make something like this possible?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible when using [asciidoctor](http://asciidoctor.org/), don't know about they python processor.

As of [Here](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor/blob/v1.5.2/test/reader_test.rb#L1075) you can see how it is used in the test harness.

```
On our quest we go...
ifdef::holygrail[There is a holy grail!]
There was much rejoicing.
```